# Como aplico una fuente a todos los textos de mi pagina web?

Tags: html, css

Quiero poner una fuente que se aplique a toda la pagina web, la misma fuente.

Comment: body{font-family: 'Nombre de la fuente''}

Answer (score 3):

Como la etiqueta `<font>` es obsoleta en versiones de HTML 4.0, puedes usar:

```
 <style type="text/css">

     body{
            font-family:"Nombre de Fuente";
            font-size: 20px;
        }

  </style>
```

Para indicar que todo lo escrito dentro de `<body>` tenga las propiedades definidas.

Ejemplo:

```css
body{
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: blue;        
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>StackOverflow.com</h1>

<p>Stack Overflow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software. Lo construyes y lo administras tú como parte de la red de sitios de preguntas y respuestas de Stack Exchange. Con tu ayuda, trabajamos juntos para crear una biblioteca de respuestas detalladas para todas las preguntas sobre programación, desarrollo y uso de software..</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes especificarlo en el css de esta forma así aplicas la fuente a todo el documento

```
*{
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

También así, de esta forma aplicas la fuente a todo el body que es el que contiene todo lo visual

```
body{
    font-family: Arial;
}
```